# Strategy Pattern implementation in JavaScript code error

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, jestjs

I have the *Calculation.js* file, *CalculationStrategy.js*, and *CalculationStrategyB.js*.

I want to implement the **Strategy Pattern** to these files. However, when I used **Jest** to test the files. I have an error that `this.stragtegy.doOperation is not a function`.

I did follow the tutorial to implement the **Strategy Pattern** by using the `Calculation` file as a base but I don't know why this happens.

*Calculation.js*

```
class Calculation {
constructor(a, b, op) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.op = op;
    this.stragtegy = null;
}

static Create(a, b, op){
    return new Calculation(a, b, op);
}

 GetResults() {
    return this.op(this.a,this.b)
}
addOperationToName(fn){
    return function(name){
        const operation = name + ' is an operation';
        return fn(operation);
    }
}

sayOperation(name){
    return name;
}

obtainStructor(){
    return this.a +' '+ this.b;
}

set strategy(stragtegy){
    this.stragtegy = stragtegy;
}

doOperation(){
    return this.stragtegy.doOperation();
}
}
module.exports = Calculation;
```

*CalculationStrategy.js*

```
class CalculationStrategy{
doAction(){
    return 'This is Calculation Strategy 1';
}
}
module.exports = CalculationStrategy;
```

CalculationStrategyB.js

```
class CalculationStrategyB{
doAction(){
    return 'This is Calculation Strategy 2';
}
}
module.exports = CalculationStrategyB;
```

*CalculationStrategy.test.js*

```
const calculation = require('../src/models/Calculation');
const calculationStrategy = require('../src/CalculationStrategy');
const calculationStrategyB = require('../src/CalculationStrategyB');
const Product = require('../src/Operations/Product');

test('Test Strategy of Calculation', () => {
//I need to test the get results function
let op = Product;
let customCalculation = new calculation(1,2, op);
const strategy = new calculationStrategy();
const strategyB = new calculationStrategyB();
customCalculation.stragtegy = strategy;
expect(customCalculation.doOperation()).toBe('This is Calculation Strategy 1');
customCalculation.stragtegy = strategyB;
expect(customCalculation.doOperation()).toBe('This is Calculation Strategy 2');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of conflicting variables.

```
let calculation = new calculation(1,2, op);
```

You can work around it by using different names or different naming patterns. For example:

```
const Calculation = require('../src/models/Calculation');
const CalculationStrategy = require('../src/CalculationStrategy');
const CalculationStrategyB = require('../src/CalculationStrategyB');
const Product = require('../src/Operations/Product');

test('Test Strategy of Calculation', () => {
  let op = Product;
  let calculation = new Calculation(1,2, op);
  const strategy = new CalculationStrategy();
  const strategyB = new CalculationStrategyB();
  calculation.stragtegy = strategy;
  expect(calculation.doOperation()).toBe('This is Calculation Strategy 1');
  calculation.stragtegy = strategyB;
  expect(calculation.doOperation()).toBe('This is Calculation Strategy 2');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Culprit :-

`let calculation = new calculation(1,2, op);`

Use a different name for your `let` declaration like so :-

`let customCalculation = new calculation(1,2, op);`